# PHP Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php

Getting above error while running the php code. Could you please help me to solve this?

Code -

```
else 
    { 
        $reason = (string) $content->errors; 
        array_walk($reason, function($v) 
            { 
                return $v->message; 
            }
        ); 
        $reason = implode(PHP_EOL, $reason); 
        addLog('...Unable to fetch data. Reason:' . $reason); 
        exit; 
    }
```

Error -

```
PHP Warning:  array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /imrmnt/vvdownload/php/imr_V5_full_prod.php on line 485
PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /imrmnt/vvdownload/php/imr_V5_full_prod.php on line 486
```

Comment: Reason needs to be an array, but you cast to string before. Why?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Shall I comment this line?

Comment: What @MarkusZeller means is that you should remove the cast. The line _$reason = (string) $content->errors;_ should read _$reason = $content->errors;_

Comment: yeah! or cast it  as array like this : `(array)  `